# Migrated My Profile link still pointing to the old MOSS server

Tags: migration, sharepoint-2007, mysite, ssp

Migrated a MOSS content DB to a brand new farm. The My Sites also were on the same content DB. Then the SSP also was migrated over. However, the My Profile link is not binding to the restored My Sites but rather to the old MOSS server. Anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, It was a mistake by our client. They had modified the MySite's default.aspx to redirect to the old server on page load. *Sigh

Appreciate all the help :-)!